# Differences in passing the data as a parameter or taking it from event object in event handlers functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

What is, if there is any difference in performance or execution when you send data to event handler as a parameter or you use the value from an event object. So, in this example, taken from the tutorial about React whose repository you can find [here](https://github.com/btholt/complete-intro-to-react-v4).

```
{photos.map((photo, index) => (
  <img
    onClick={this.handleIndexClick}
    data-index={index}
    key={photo.value}
    src={photo.value}
    className={index === active ? "active" : ""}
    alt="animal thumbnail"
  />
))}
```

There is a click handler, that takes the index from the event object and then sets the state based on that index.

```
handleIndexClick = event => {
  this.setState({
    active: +event.target.dataset.index
  });
};
```

Is there any difference in performance if we send the index directly as a parameter?

```
<img
  onClick={this.handleIndexClick(index)}
  data-index={index}
  key={photo.value}
  src={photo.value}
  className={index === active ? "active" : ""}
  alt="animal thumbnail"
/>
```

And then function would like this:

```
handleIndexClick = index => {
  this.setState({
    active: +index
  });
};
```

Which approach is better and preferred?

Comment: Miniscule and probably wont matter performance wise unless doing thousands of these in a row.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no difference in perfomance between two ways of getting index value in methods. 
Event objects is important part of React and JS at all. So tutorial teaches you how to work with events and how extract values from event object.
You can choose what way is more comfortable for you and use it.
I prefer pass values directly to a function. But if i work with inputs, i extract its value from event object.

Answer (score 0):

The difference, if any would be very small/ nothing. So I think the question comes down to what is more readable and maintainable. I would go with the following personally.

```
<img
  onClick={this.handleIndexClick(index)}
  data-index={index}
  key={photo.value}
  src={photo.value}
  className={index === active ? "active" : ""}
  alt="animal thumbnail"
/>

handleIndexClick = index => () => {
  this.setState({
    active: +index
  });
};
```

I think the above is easier to read and maintain. And I also believe it is less characters used. In your first example it's `324` characters and second is `258`. So would technically cost less memory making your package smaller which will result in `faster compiling`. `Runtime performance` I believe would be equal. But like I said in the grand scheme, doesn't really matter, and comes down to how `readable` and `maintainable` your code is.

Also I guess you don't need to pass the `event` to you `onClickHandler`. But if you had to pass a `parameter` and the event you would do something like this.

```
handleIndexClick = index => event => {
  this.setState({
    active: +index
  });

  // Can use the event if needed
};
```